# Изображение в проекте AndroidStudio по условию

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста. Попал в тупиковую ситуацию. Пробую функцию отображения картинки/значка в приложении, в текстовом варианте справился с задачей, но как с изображением быть не доходит до меня.

Есть рабочий код

```
val StImg = if (response.body()!!.SSL[0].St == "1") {
                        "1"
                    } else {
                        ""
                    } 

views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetSt,
                            "$StImg")
```

и разметка xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetSt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Код работает если в JSON в пункте **St** указана единица(1), то она отображается в проекте, если в пункте **St** пусто или другое значение, то в результате пусто.

Но до меня ни как не доходит как текстовые значения заменить картинкой, т.е если в **St** 1, то вместо единицы в проекте появлялась картинка из проекта лежащая в папке drawable. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Для начала нужно понимать, что в TextView может быть текст, а картинка быть не может.

Comment: @Эникейщик, это не совсем верно) Картинку можно в TextView отобразить через ImageSpan: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan. Хотя в данном конкретном случае это явно не стоит делать)

Comment: Вам надо использовать ImageView. Примерно так: ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.imageViewId); iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_file_name_in_low_case_with_underscores_as_word_separator);